# Trie to store duplicate substrings efficiently in C++

Tags: c++, trie

I have written a program to implement a basic Trie in C++, every node having 26 child pointers (for English alphabets), and the Node class looks like this:

```
class Node
{
public:
       Node* parent;
       Node* child[26];
       unsigned int number_of_children;
....
}
```

Now, there could be many words like {snapple, dapple}, {distract, attract}, etc, in which  more than 3 alphabets match. I want to store distinct entries of these sub-words (like from the example above - apple, tract), and let others point to them (like {s-n-ptr_to_apple, d-ptr_to_apple}, {d-i-s-ptr_to_tract, a-t-ptr_to_tract}). I believe it is best to handle this while inserting a word itself, instead of having a function which performs this after the insertions have completed.

I need some help in designing this, at present I am not looking into execution efficiency, rather the code/design should be compact. Currently, I visit a node and check all the non-null siblings (by traversing along the sibling's children) for matching with the input word, and then store the pointers in case there is a match of say 4 words (but the code is getting longer and obfuscating).

Comment: IMHO, what you are asking for is not worth doing.  As your list of words grows, you are going to end up using more memory, more pointer indirections, more logic complexities just to track the substrings then you would just leaving the full words intact.

Comment: I agree, currently my code fails for several test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Traditional tries compress on common prefixes.  You, in essence, want to compress on common suffixes.  The easiest way is to just build your trie entries backward.

Now, this means you must read the string backwards into the trie.

Comment: As I think on it, I can't imagine any real reason a clever trie can't do both.  Totally doable (if hard)

Comment: I thought of it, once you have a shared suffix, it becomes virtually impossible to add words.  Which means all compression must come after all inserts.  Which doesn't save you much.

Comment: fries, fred, aries and arc.  [fr] forks to [ies] and [ed].  [ar] forks to a shared [ies] and [rc].  We reuse [ies] for both.  Then we add friesz.  Now add friesz.  We have to know that the [ies] suffix has an incoming count of 2, and fork it into two copies.  We then add ariesz.  Now we have to recognize that ies+z matches with iesz perfectly.  This will get really complex really fast.